# Alternative way removes security warning when using ANDROID_ID and how to get the device id?

Tags: android, android-security

public static String getDeviceID(Context mContext) {

```
    String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    return deviceId;
}
```

This shows a security warning,

"Using 'getString' to get device identifiers is not recommended "

How to resolve this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really "resolve" this warning.

Lint is trying to move you from *android ID* to *advertising id* if possible, because for most use cases it's better for user. If you want to disable the warning `@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")` takes care of that.